# Include documentation of another project

Tags: doxygen

I have a library (e.g. 'mylib') that derives from another library (e.g. 'GMatTensor'), e.g. by deriving from a class. Now I would like to include 'GMatTensor' in the documentation of 'mylib' e.g. to show derived methods.

#### What works

For my library of the following structure:

```
docs/Doxyfile
include/mylib/mylib.hpp
```

I have a `Doxyfile` containing

```
INPUT = ../include/mylib
```

I then include the external library from the location where it got installed. I did it with conda, so what works is

```
( cat Doxyfile ; echo "INPUT += ${CONDA_PREFIX}/include/GMatTensor") | doxygen -
```

#### What doesn't work

The above results in long paths:

[image]

So the question: **can the paths of the 'external' library be made more readable (and less system dependent)** (without cloning the 'external' library locally?

Comment: Which version of doxygen? Did you have a look at the setting: `STRIP_FROM_PATH`?

Comment: Thanks @albert that is exactly what is needed! It would be great is you could post it as an answer for future reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using doxygen and  especially when using full paths names (like in `INPUT += ${CONDA_PREFIX}/include/GMatTensor")` be aware of the settings of

- `FULL_PATH_NAMES`
- `STRIP_FROM_PATH`
- `STRIP_FROM_INC_PATH`

see the documentation (https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#config_input) for a definition of these settings and what is required in the specific case.